# Unable to link GoogleAnalytics 3.10 with XCode 5 (missing required architecture x86_64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

In my app I am trying to use Google Analytics3.10 . I have followed the steps below:

1 Downloaded GA for iOS 3.10
2 Imported content of /GoogleAnalytics/Library/ into group "GoogleAnalytics"
3 Added Build Phases CoreData,SystemConfiguration and libz.dylb
4 Initialize the [GAI sharedInstance] in my AppDelegate.

Deployment target for app is 7.0
I am getting this error while build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: No its not, I am trying to integrate Google Analytics 3.10 in which google has already added support for 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added libsqlite3.0.dylib to the Link Binary With Libraries in the Build Phases tab. It worked!!!!